# Let A - linear operator, B - non-linear operator. Is it possible that A commutes with B?

Tags: operator-theory

Let A - linear operator, B - non-linear operator. Is it possible that A commutes with B? What theorem prohibits this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is posible. For instance, it will happen if $A$ is the identity operator.